# How do I use sbt from a Github Codespace terminal where Scala was installed by Metals?

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, github-codespaces, scala-metals

I am new to Scala development and would like to keep it entirely in the cloud. I am looking for the easiest way to get a fully functional workspace in a Github Codespace, including the Metals extension/language server, but also be able to use `scala` and `sbt` in the terminal.

So far my approach is to start a codespace with a simple Scala project, including a `build.sbt` file. Using VSCode Desktop, I connect and install the Metals extension in the codespace. That works just fine and I can now run tests etc from the Metals tab. But I am stuck on how to use `scala` or `sbt` directly from the VSCode terminal, the commands themselves are unknown. Clearly Metals uses them under the hood, so they are there in the codespace, but I cannot find the paths in the logs.

Is there a way to find a (non-dynamic) path to the `sbt` that Metals uses and then alias that in the terminal? Or should I be building the codespace devcontainer with Scala in the first place, something like https://github.com/zenchicken/codespaces-scala? That seems unnecessary when Metals builds everything automatically just fine, based on the standard devcontainer.